# Angular img loading directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to make a simple directive. When the image is loading, the img src will be set to an `@Input()` string field. On load, the image will be set to the original src value (or at least how I am trying to implement it).

I was using the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38837619/843443
but is isn't a directive, and thus would require a number of changes wherever I use images.

My first attempt:

loading-img.directive.ts:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tohLoadingImg]'
})
export class LoadingImgDirective {
  imgSrc: String;

  @Input()
  spinnerSrc: String;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.imgSrc = el.nativeElement.src;
    el.nativeElement.src = this.spinnerSrc;
  }

  @HostListener('load') onLoad() {
    this.el.nativeElement.src = this.imgSrc;
  }

}
```

from:

```html
<img src="{{hero.imgUrl}}" alt="Random first slide">
```

to:

```html
<img src="{{hero.imgUrl}}" alt="Random first slide" [tohLoadingImg]="'/assets/ring.svg'">
```

Error:

```
Can't bind to 'tohLoadingImg' since it isn't a known property of 'img'. (".imgUrl}}" alt="Random first slide">-->
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what are you trying to do! spinner icon?

Comment: Yes. Spinner icon or something like that.

Comment: have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963444/angular-2-material-progress-spinner-display-as-overlay/43243097#43243097)

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting it... I was trying to make a custom directive on an img tag... are you suggesting just making a component that is essentially a wrapper for an img? I think I could do that... just checking.

Comment: yes. using it as a component is the best way to achieve.

Comment: you are not  using the directive correctly here: it should be: `<img src="{{hero.imgUrl}}" alt="Random first slide"  tohLoadingImg [spinnerSrc]="'/assets/ring.svg'">`

Comment: That got me past the error message, but didn't fix my issue... something else must be wrong.

Comment: <img tohLoadingImg [src]="hero.imgUrl" alt="Random first slide" [spinnerSrc]="'/assets/ring.svg'">

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```js
import {
  Directive,
  Attribute,
  Renderer2,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[uiImageLoader]'
})
export class UiImageLoaderDirective {
  constructor(
    @Attribute('loader') public loader: string,
    @Attribute('onErrorSrc') public onErrorSrc: string,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.loader);
    }

  @HostListener('load') onLoad() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.el.nativeElement.src);
  }
  @HostListener('error') onError() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.onErrorSrc);
  }
}
```

### USAGE

```html
<img
  uiImageLoader
  onErrorSrc="/assets/images/no-available-800.png"
  loader="/assets/images/image-loader.svg"
  [src]="post.imagePath" [alt]="post.title">
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Aravind for the direction. This is how I solved it (by using a component rather than a directive):

spinner-img.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'toh-spinner-img',
  templateUrl: './spinner-img.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner-img.component.scss']
})
export class SpinnerImgComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() imgSrc: String;
  @Input() spinnerSrc: String;
  @Input() imgContainerClass: String;

  loading: boolean = true

  onLoad() {
    this.loading = false;
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

spinner-img.component.html:

```
<div [class]="imgContainerClass">
  <img *ngIf="loading" src="{{spinnerSrc}}" alt="loading"/>
  <img [hidden]="loading" (load)="onLoad()" src="{{imgSrc}}" alt="Hero Pic"/>
</div>
```

And in use:

```
 <toh-spinner-img [imgSrc]="hero.imgUrl" [spinnerSrc]="'/assets/ring.svg'"></toh-spinner-img>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I made my own image loader to show a placeholder while the images are loading. I first used the code from [@Whisher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356380/whisher), but stumbled on some issues. For example, I was using Server Side Rendering (SSR) and thus had some small issues to work out.

### Code

In the end, I came up with this:

```js
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import {
  AfterContentInit,
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  Inject,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  PLATFORM_ID,
  Renderer2,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'img[imageLoader]',
})
export class ImageLoaderDirective implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @Input()
  public src!: string;
  @Input()
  public loaderSrc: string = '/assets/image-loading.png';
  @Input()
  public errorSrc: string = '/assets/image-not-found.png';
  @Input()
  public lazyLoad: boolean = true;

  private alreadyTriedLoading: boolean = false;
  private alreadyTriedError: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef<HTMLImageElement>,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.src);

    if (this.lazyLoad) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'loading', 'lazy');
    }
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    if (this.shouldDisplayLoader()) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.loaderSrc);
    } else {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.src);
    }
  }

  @HostListener('load')
  public onLoad(): void {
    if (!this.alreadyTriedLoading) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.src);
    }
    this.alreadyTriedLoading = true;
  }

  @HostListener('error')
  public onError(): void {
    if (!this.alreadyTriedError) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', this.errorSrc);
    }
    this.alreadyTriedError = true;
  }

  private shouldDisplayLoader(): boolean {
    return (
      isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) && !this.el.nativeElement.complete
    );
  }
}
```

This should work with most use cases. When the server is trying to use the `imageLoader` it will just set image and not do anything with it. When it's the browser trying to use the `imageLoader` it will first check the state of the image. It might happen that the image has already been loaded, due to cache, so in that case it won't show the loader. Otherwise, it will display the loader and show the original image after it is done loading.
I also added lazy loading to it, but that was personal preference.

### Example

If you were to use all fields, it might look something like this:

```html
<img
  [src]="product.image_path"
  alt="An image of a product being displayed"
  imageLoader
  loaderSrc="/assets/loading.gif"
  errorSrc="/assets/error.png"
  [lazyLoad]="false"
/>
```

While the directive might work without using the `OnInit` and `AfterContentInit`, I used these two lifecycle hooks to make them work with property binding. When I tried [@Whisher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356380/whisher)'s code, I ran into the issue that the src would be empty. Also, because I use the `src` as an input, angular changes it to something like `ng-reflect-src`, so this would mean the browser doesn't load the image initially. To fix this, I set the `src` again in the `ngOnInit` hook.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with using a directive

```
@Directive({ selector: '[imgLoader]', standalone: true })
export class ImgLoaderDirective {
  private readonly el = inject(ElementRef);
  private readonly renderer = inject(Renderer2);
  private readonly vcRef = inject(ViewContainerRef);

  @Input()
  set imgLoader(loaderSize: string) {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'style', 'display: none');
    const loaderComponent = this.vcRef.createComponent(LoaderComponent);
    loaderComponent.instance.size = loaderSize;
  }

  @HostListener('load') onLoad() {
    this.displayImage();
  }

  @HostListener('error') onError() {
    this.displayImage();
  }

  private displayImage() {
    this.vcRef.clear();
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'style', 'display: block');
  }
}
```