# Display loading icon while images loads in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, loading

l have array of satellite images animation with buttons controls using angular  . l would like to show a icon loading while the images fully loaded for each image , then hide loading icon .

So there is any way to do that please ?

[live code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g8q8j4?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Check if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000252/how-to-show-spinner-in-angular-6

Comment: Thank you for commented . l am not using http . l am using new Image() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer maybe can help you, I thought `loadstart` have problems because It also can't work in my easy HTML javascript environment [Codepen](https://codepen.io/unnhao/pen/XWdxGLe). I don't know MDN document how to use it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38837619/6735893